# Windows Server Storage Pool migrate to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2012, storage

I have a PC that is currently running Windows Server 2012 R2 and It has 4 HDD's in a storage pool. I would like to uninstall windows server on that machine and replace it with Windows 10 (there is no need for Windows server, it's a bit overkill).

I know that Windows 10 also supports storage pools but my current storage pool, would that have to be wiped and stat over or Windows 10 will recognize the storage pool and continue to use it as a storage pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to just install Windows 10 on a separate HDD and see what happens. 
Windows 10 will correctly pick up the storage pools (Storage Spaces) and everything works as expected.